# CLion WSL Debugger Version Not Supported

Tags: valgrind, clion, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've recently installed WSL (WSL 1, not WSL 2) on my Windows 10 64-bit with Ubuntu 20.04 (latest LTS version) and CLion 2020.1.1 (latest version). Using WSL, my CLion can run and execute C programs normally but according to the Toolchains page, the Debugger version is not supported for some reason (picture attached). I'm pretty sure everything's up to date though.

[image: CLion Toolchains page]

And how do I find Valgrind executable file on my system? I've installed Valgrind on Ubuntu according to [Valgrind Memcheck](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/memory-profiling-with-valgrind.html) on the CLion Help page but I'm stuck on finding the executable file. Should I just search 'Valgrind' in my disk? If it helps, below is the Ubuntu terminal after I installed Valgrind.

[image: Ubuntu Installed Valgrind]

Comment: Default installation of valgrind executable is `/usr/bin/valgrind`. As for Debugger it's just a warning. Everything should work fine.

Comment: wow. that solved everything